# cordova to mysql database connection

Tags: cordova

I create cordova app for android device. I need to connect that app with hosted mysql database to fetching some data. looking for sample codes, videos for connect with mysql database with my app.

Comment: This does not belong here. Flagged to close

Comment: On SO we cant suggest tools and videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for posting/getting data from web.
for example you want to create a log-in screen and verify your input through parsing JSON.

```
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var code = $("#code").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var dataString = "code=" + code + "&password=" + password;
        if ($.trim(code).length > 0 & $.trim(password).length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "urlstring",
                data: dataString,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType:"JSON",
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () { $("#button").html('Connecting...'); },
                success: function (success) {



                    console.log(success);
                    if (success[0].success == true) {
                        alert("Login Successfull!");
                        $("#button").html('Connected');

                    }
                    else if (success[0].success == false) {
                        alert("Wrong Password!");
                        $("#button").html('Login');
                    }
                }
            });
        } return false;
    });
```

Comment: Please Winwin Fortuno, would you know if is it possible connecting at mysql db directly? with no webservices like php or asp? Thanks.